# 'False Positive' detection in corona testing using ML techniques

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, clustering, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I am working on the detection of false positive test result in COVID-19 testing. The false positive sample are mainly due to the contamination during the routine testing. Samples are  handled in batch of 96 (plat) and this plate will go inside the PCR machine. There are a couple of possibilities that virus from one sample transmits to other samples.

I have created a couple of features such as number of positive samples in row, column, how many samples are consecutively positive, the nearest distance to the positive samples for each sample.

I want to deploy ML model to detect the false positive sample, since data is unlabeled, I am thinking following techniques

1. Unsupervised Anomaly Detection to simply detect the contaminated ones
2. First develop a clustering machine learning model using dataset features including both positive and negative samples. The contaminated samples (false positive) must cluster with the negatives samples

Then a classifier model to predict positive or negative. If the classifier calls a sample negative, but it's labeled positive, then that's our tentative contaminated sample.

Any other possibility to this problem?

Comment: What's your plan for evaluation? Without knowing the true positivity status, how will you know if your classifier is picking actual false positives or not? It's also not entirely clear how you use something like "number of positives in a row" as an input feature, when you will ultimately determine later on that some of those samples weren't actually positive.

Comment: well end goal is to determine while there is contamination in the plate (96 samples) or not , if there is enough evidence of contamination whole plate will go for re-process. There is certain pattern of contamination, most commonly it is seen in the columns ,   since specimens are placed in the plate from  top to bottom one after other column , more chances of contamination occur in the vertical direction

Comment: For evaluation ideally it should be manually done , since so far contamination in the plates is judge manually